# How to match anything after a question mark in a Google Analytics goals regex?

Tags: regex, google-analytics, escaping, re2

I am trying to fix the goal tracking in Google Analytics for an eCommerce site. It was working, until one of the Steps URL was changed. See below to what it was set before and what it is now after searching.

**Before**

- URL: website.com/Search/2343-5456-3423-5675
- Name: Search
- Regex: /Search.*

**Present**

- URL: website.com/Availability?value=abc&value=123&step=1
- Name: Availability
- Regex (not working): /Availability?.*

---

## Edit 1:

This is a cross-domain goal tracking. So a user lands on Website A, and to check out, they click and go to Website B where the cart is to purchase something. The cross-domain setup is working, and this only broke after one of the steps was changed.

1. Page 1: website.com/
2. Page 2: website.com/Availability?value=abc&value=123&step=1
3. Page 3: website.com/Booking/Index/444-333-222-111
4. Page 4: website.com/Booking/ResortAndGuest/444-333-222-111
5. Page 5: website.com/Booking/Payment/444-333-222-111

[image: Google Analytics Setup]

---

Thank you!

Comment: try this \/Availability\?.*

Comment: @SafayatRahaman I just tried that, didn't work!

Comment: can you provide code sample?

Comment: Should be `/Availability\?` or `/Availability(?:\?|$)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Forgot to reply! Didn't work unfortunately. I'll add the URL's and the Goal Setup in an edit, maybe that'll help. If it matters, this is cross-domain goal tracking.

Comment: @crentist  Can you try `/Availability\?.*` or `/Availability.*` ?

Comment: The one for index should `^/?$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some observations:

1. `/*` looks dubious as a regular expression for `Index`. It will match a slash character any number of times, including zero times. In other words, it will also match **nothing** - see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/0YvEPs/1).
2. As others have pointed out, to match a literal question mark, it needs to be escaped by preceding with a backslash - so `\?` instead of `?`. As far as I can tell, `Availability(\?.*|$)` *ought* to work - see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iGO2rq/1). Are you sure the problem isn't elsewhere?
3. The final three regular expressions may or may not be sufficient - if there might be the possibility of something like `/Booking/Indexer` for example, the `/Booking/Index.*` regular expression would match this, which could be wrong - see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/J2sEGS/1). To rule this out, consider an alternative such as `/Booking/Index([/?].*|$)` - see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LFIBzJ/1).